# More than one D.S.?

Tags: notation, musical-forms, repeats

Is it possible to have more than one D.S. when charting a song? if so, how would you know which segno?

This would be a great tool for saving space in a chart.

Answer (score 6):

D.S.  and D.SS. are sometimes used.  Same for codas.  Possibly useful for saving paper when a score won't have to be sight-read!  But, in these days of computer score preparation, it's little extra work to play safe and write it out if there's any chance of confusion.

I have seen parts almost as silly as this!

[image]

Comment: Awesome example! One good reason for saving space though is to get the entire song on a single sheet of paper and avoid a page turn.